# Azure Data Factory fails with UPSERT for every table with a TIMESTAMP column

Tags: azure-data-factory, upsert, sql-timestamp

my azure data factory throws the error "Cannot update a timestamp column" for every table with a `TIMESTAMP` column.

> ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Cannot update a timestamp column.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=272,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=272,State=1,Message=Cannot update a timestamp column.,},],'

**I do not want to update the column** itself. But even when I delete it from column mapping, it crashes. Here it is not yet deleted:

[image]

I get that `TIMESTAMP` is not a simple datetime and is updated automatically whenever a another column in that row is updated.

> The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time.

But how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue, and on my ADF, if I remove the timestamp column from mapping the pipeline run with no errors.

But since this doesn't work for you, here are 2 workaround options:

Option 1 - on the source, use  a query and remove the timestamp column from the query.

Option 2 - I tried to reproduce your error, and found out that it only happens on upsert. If I use insert, it runs with no error (though it ignore the insert on the timestamp column and increment the timestamp). So you can try to insert to a staging table and then update in sql only the columns you want.